# Having trouble getting jQuery toggle script to run inside jQuery Dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I've got a menu that uses the `jQuery` `toggle` function to open and close a sub-menu. This is working perfectly fine in all of my pages, BUT, when I try to add this same menu and sub-menu into a `jQuery` `dialog box` it will not open the sub-menu.

Here is my `index.php` code, including the `javascript` includes from the `<head>` of the page:

```
<script src="javascripts/jq/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jq/jquery-v1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jq/jquery-v1.9.2.js"></script>

<p align="center" id="temp_menuOpener">[Click Here to Toggle Menu]</p>

<div id="temp_menu">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td class="ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br cus-dialog-content"><?php include("includes/menu.php");?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
    $( "#temp_menu" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 'inherit'});
    $( "#temp_menuOpener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#temp_menu" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
</script>
```

Here is my `menu.php` code:

```
<script>
$(function()
    {
    $('.schedOpener').click(function()
        {
        $('div#submenu_sched').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="menu">
    <div class="menu schedOpener">
    <img src="/roster/images/menu/schedule.png" border="0" title="Schedule" alt="Schedule">
    </div>

    <div id="submenu_sched">
        <div class="menu">
        <a href="/roster/sched/sched_month.php" target="_parent"><img src="/roster/images/menu/sched_month.png" border="0" title="Schedule Month View" alt="Schedule Month View"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The CSS for `submenu_sched` is set to `display:none;`.

So, like I said, this menu works perfectly until it's added to a `dialog box` and then it fails. Simply removing `id="temp_menu"` from the `<div>` will make it work, but that also removes it from the `dialog box`.

I tried adding this to a jsfiddle, but I couldn't get the `dialog box` to work at all, even when I chose the `jQuery 1.8.3` library framework. So instead I set it up on my test server to make it so you can at least see what I mean. You will notice on my test server there is more to the menu, and the page itself, than what I've posted here. I am trying to keep the static to noise ratio at a good level :)

[IWACTITE](http://www.iwactite.com/test)

Comment: in order your code work at jsfiddle you need to use clear html, but in your example i see PHP - <?php include("includes/menu.php");?>. It is not possible to know wnat should be there.

Comment: I've never seen multiple versions of jQuery included in a page, maybe that's the problem? I'm also struggling to find any JavaScript code related to your sub-menu.

Comment: @Graham Thank you for the reply and for the good suggestion. I've got a jQuery Datepicker, the Dialog Box as well as a Color Picker being used on the same page and they all require a different version of jQuery for some reason. I did actually try removing them one at a time to see how it effected each of the scripts, but one by one they stopped working. I haven't used jQuery much, other than for pre-made scripts, but I would have thought that the newest version would cover all previous versions as well. Strange.

Comment: I just had a look at your code, and I put a breakpoint on the line $('div#submenu_sched').toggle(); When I clicked schedule and stepped through the code using the Firefox debugger, the Monthly View and Full View options were displayed, but as I continued stepping through, they were hidden again.  Is that basically the problem?

Comment: A brief look (opening up Fiebug/WebKit DOM Inspector), right-clicking the submenu and setting 'Break on attribute modification', revealed that with the dialog it is first being shown and then being hidden again. Seemingly this happens entirely within the chain of events set off by your one call to jQuery toggle. Weird!

Comment: I think you need to move your sub-menu JavaScript outside of the popup. When I look at the DOM, it's missing, but there in your source code

Comment: @markpsmith I'm not sure what you are saying when you talk about putting a "breakpoint" in, that's new terminology for me. The problem is that the submenu will not appear when the menu (and submenu) are put into a dialog box.

Comment: @Graham Yes, this menu and submenu work perfect when outside of the dialog box, is it not possible to have them inside it? Maybe I'm trying to do something that it wasn't designed to do? That's typical :)

Comment: @Barney It is weird, right? I mean, I've got other jQuery scripts running within a dialog box in other places on my site. One of them is the datepicker and that works without any issues, so maybe it's this toggle feature that isn't compatible?

Comment: THATS IT!! I just changed all of the `.toggle();` to `.show();` and it works! So it must be that the `toggle` function doesn't work within the dialog box. Weird!!

Comment: ...but now I can't close it, the submenu stays open until you click on something else. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, after a while playing around on jsFiddle, I've figured all the problems out. First the JavaScript shouldn't be inside the dialog. Secondly, you have to use `($("#temp_menu").dialog("isOpen") == true) ? $("#temp_menu").dialog("close") : $("#temp_menu").dialog("open");` to compare whether to open or close the dialog.

Here's my working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/uVVES/)
and here's the fullscreen version [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/uVVES/embedded/result/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and all of the work you put into this! Much appreciation! So it looks like what you did was basically create the effect of the `.toggle();` function by using the `jQuery` equivalent of the `if()else()` statements used in `php`?

Comment: The if else statement I used is called a Ternary Operator, you can read more about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx) :)

Comment: FYI, I will be back to select an answer, I just got put onto something else at the moment and won't be back to this for a few hours. Once I test your answer on my live project, I'll be able to select it. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, I've tried it out. Ultimately everything will work just by taking the JavaScript out of the Dialog, like you suggested. Leaving the original `temp_menu` script with `.toggle();` works perfectly. I've updated the fiddle in case someone else wants to refer to it. The main reason I'm so stuck on keeping the `.toggle();` function instead of using your solution, is because I'm using it in other places on the website where there is no Dialog box being used. I want to make sure that if I ever have to troubleshoot this site down the road, or make changes to it, that it makes sense to me. Thanks!